# <template is="dom-if"> = "Wrong Attribute Value"

Tags: html, polymer, webstorm

I'm going through the code analysis on my project in WebStorm.  This polymer template is working fine and as far as I can tell is correct according to the docs, but [[image]webstorm](/questions/tagged/webstorm) keeps throwing the following warning on the `dom-if` part:

> Wrong attribute value

Code:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{showspark}}">
<div class="box-body text-center" style="padding-top:10px;">
    <span id="sline">
    </span>
</div>
</template>
```

The only recourse it offers is to inject language or reference:

[image]

How can I make this warning go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please vote for [WEB-23586](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23586) to be notified on any progress with this issue. Unfortunately this error can't be suppressed; the only way to get rid of it is setting highlighting level to `<None>` using Hector icon in the lower right corner: open your .html file in editor, click the Hector icon and then move the slider to the left. See http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/changing-highlighting-level-for-the-current-file.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. Surprised that didn't come up in my search.  By "vote" do you mean star?

Comment: I mean the  thumbs up button. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241135-How-to-follow-YouTrack-issues-and-receive-notifications. Star also subscribes you to the automatic notifications, but doesn't add your vote to it